# Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT

Tags: sql-server

I am getting the following error:

> "Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not
>   allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query."

Note:

`@transientCartData` is defined as `varbinary(max)`

`@savedCartData`  is defined as `varbinary(max)`

The query:

```
exec [ecomm].[expiry_save_cart2_v1] 
@id=80094, 
@lastUpdated='2016-05-11 14:23:42.637',
@transientCartExpiryIntervalInMin='45',
@session_id='5C632166-D7D6-4F51-A87F-EED41376EEA7',
@version='TEST_VERSION',
@associated_slots='Null',
@account_id='TEST_ACCOUNT_ID',
@cookie='Null',
@transientCartData= 'TEST_DATA',
@savedCartData= 'TEST_DATA',
@data2='NULL',
@is_pricing_needed='1',
@savedCartExpiryIntervalInDays='14',
@persistentCartExpiryIntervalInDays='1',
@cart_type='PERSISTENT', 
@customerAccountId=TEST_ACCOUNT_ID
```

Then when I am trying to use `@transientCartData = CONVERT(varbinary, 'TEST_DATA', 1)`, I am getting this error:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONVERT'.

Comment: exec [ecomm].[expiry_save_cart2_v1] @id=80094 ,
@lastUpdated='2016-05-11 14:23:42.637',
@transientCartExpiryIntervalInMin='45',
@session_id='5C632166-D7D6-4F51-A87F-EED41376EEA7',
@version='TEST_VERSION',@associated_slots='Null',
@account_id='TEST_ACCOUNT_ID',
@cookie='Null',
@transientCartData= 'TEST_DATA',
@savedCartData= 'TEST_DATA',
@data2='NULL',@is_pricing_needed='1',
@savedCartExpiryIntervalInDays='14',
@persistentCartExpiryIntervalInDays='1',
@cart_type='PERSISTENT',
@customerAccountId=TEST_ACCOUNT_ID

Comment: Please post the code in your actual question.

Comment: This error is pretty self-explanatory.  Can you clue us in about the logic of converting a `VARCHAR` to a binary BLOB?

Comment: when i am trying to use @transientCartData= CONVERT(varbinary, 'TEST_DATA', 1), i am getting below error  this error Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONVERT'.

Comment: I moved your comments into your original post and formatted them properly can you please delete them from the comments?

Comment: @sam Are you running MySQL or SQL-Server? Your syntax appears to be SQL-Server, but your tag says MySQL.

Comment: Removed mysql tag, added sql-server, since that's what it appears to be.  Can't possibly be mysql.

Answer (score 2):

## SQL-Server

SQL-Server has the following syntax for [Convert](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

> CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression [ , style ] )

You code is failing due to *style* being set as **1**.

> If the data_type is a binary type, the expression must be a character expression. The expression must be composed of an even number of hexadecimal digits (0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, A, B, C, D, E, F, a, b, c, d, e, f). ...

You need to set it to **0**(default).

> Translates ASCII characters to binary bytes or binary bytes to ASCII characters...

Example convert usage, which produces *0x544553545F44415441*

```
Declare @vb as varbinary(max)
Set @vb =  CONVERT(varbinary(max), 'TEST_DATA', 0)
select @vb
```

---

## MySQL

According to the [documentation for Convert](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert) your method signature is incorrect.

CONVERT has the following MySQL syntax:

> CONVERT(expr,type), CONVERT(expr USING transcoding_name)

---

Calling a stored procedure uses [Call](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/call.html) in MySQL.

> CALL sp_name([parameter[,...]])

An example of the usage is:

```
mysql> SET @increment = 10;
mysql> CALL p(@version, @increment);
mysql> SELECT @version, @increment;
+--------------+------------+
| @version     | @increment |
+--------------+------------+
| 5.5.3-m3-log |         11 |
+--------------+------------+
```

Comment: Try `CONVERT( 'TEST_DATA', binary(10))` on its own first

Comment: is it possible to write concert function on exec stored proc query? because i am getting Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CONVERT'below is my updated query exec [ecomm].[expiry_save_cart2_v1] @id=80094 ,
@lastUpdated='2016-05-11 14:23:42.637',
@transientCartExpiryIntervalInMin='45',
@session_id='5C632166-D7D6-4F51-A87F-EED41376EEA7',
@version='TEST_VERSION',
@associated_slots='Null',
@account_id='TEST_ACCOUNT_ID',
@cookie='Null',
@transientCartData= CONVERT('TEST_DATA', binary(10)),
@savedCartData= CONVERT('TEST_DATA', binary(10)),
@data2='NULL',